# Cannot read property 'initialNavigation' of undefined - Angular v4 AoT

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having some issues trying to get AoT retrofitted into an existing application. I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'initialNavigation' of undefined
RouterInitializer.webpackJsonp.1.RouterInitializer.isLegacyDisabled
```

This is roughly what my AppModule looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      enableTracing: true,
      initialNavigation: true,
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    Http,
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configServiceFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Http, ConfigService],
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It seems like router is undefined, and the router options are undefined when this code path runs: `RouterInitializer.isLegacyDisabled` which is called from `appInitializer` in the router module.

I have no idea what to do at this point. I feel like the routes are being resolved before the APP_INITIALIZER promise is complete.

This seems to work fine in JIT but AOT complication craps itself. If you need more details please let me know.

EDIT: Looks like I can get past the error if I comment out the APP_INITIALIZER. But I noticed the router uses it too to initialise, is there a way I can make the router wait for me to initialise first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APP_INITIALIZER Was causing this since the Router now hooks on to it.

A solution would be to not use it at all to bootstrap the configuration, the router has a way of manually starting it by changing its setting `initialNavigation` to false.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  initialNavigation: false,
}),
```

So I moved the APP_INITIALIZER provider into app.component.ts

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: Http,
    private configService: ConfigService,
) {
    // initialise routes once config is loaded
    configServiceFactory(http, configService).subscribe(() => router.initialNavigation());
}
```

Note: configServiceFactory is basically this:

```
return http.get('config.json') // or your remote config service
    .map(m => m.json())
    .do(config => configService.setAppConfig(config)) // store it somewhere
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error getting config for app initialisation', err);
        return err;
    });
```